# LogCat not displaying TAG "SMS"

Tags: android, logcat, ddms

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Log.e("SMS","Hello World");   //not showing
    Log.v("SMS","Hello World");   //not showing
    Log.i("SMS","Hello World");   //not showing
    Log.d("SMS","Hello World");   //not showing

    Log.i("sms","Hello World");   //showing
}
```

Why the Logging in the Logcat is not working for some line in the above code??

Comment: +1 superb marking...Glad to know the reason if this is really true.

Comment: is it showing other logs ? if not i will suggest you to restart your eclipse. this kind of things happens sometimes.

Comment: Try using the Filter to search for "Hello"...see if you spot it...Also make sure the logcat is set on verbose mode

Comment: I can reproduce this. Maybe "SMS" is some kind of reserved internal tag?

Comment: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/5ffbcf061e216cc6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some tags that don't go to the default buffer, as has been stated.

You can view them by specifying which buffer to view with the "-b" logcat option. Check section *Viewing Alternative Log Buffers* of [Using LogCat](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html#startingLogcat) to view the different buffers available. For example, to see the "SMS" logcat messages, start logcat with:

```
adb logcat -b radio
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a separate buffer for all telephony related log messages, whichwon't appear in default LogCat window.

Comment: can u spot out any other telephony related tags??

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html#alternativeBuffers
There are 3.  radio, events and main