# Android Log.d("SMS", str) messages are missing in action

Tags: android, logging, sms

I am sure I must just be missing something obvious but this is currently baffling me.

I have a class which extends BroadcastReceiver this class is setup as a receiver int he manifest and it does correctly capture the sms received intent.

```
package gull.sana.textit;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("SMSReceiver", "Intent received");
        //---get the SMS message passed in---
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String str = "";            
        if (bundle != null)
        {
            //---retrieve the SMS message received---
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
            for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
                str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();                     
                str += " :";
                str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                str += "\n";        
            }
            Log.d("SMS", str);
            //---display the new SMS message---
            Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }
}
```

Now when I send in an SMS message I always get the first log message `Log.d("SMSReceiver", "Intent received");` and I always get the  **Toast** as I would expect, however, I never get the `Log.d("SMS", str);`

Am I doing something wrong? Why does the Toast appear yet the log on the line before never does?

Comment: Do you see either of the `Log` statements? Are you positive it's not there? Are you pulling log files from the wrong device maybe?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't filtering for "SMSReceiver" instead of just "SMS"?

Comment: Yes it is definitely the correct (and only android device), and I always get the first Log message but never the second.  The if statement is definitely entered as the Toast always appears too.

Comment: I have no filters set on logcat as I can see all other log messages from the phone.

Comment: Clean, Compile again, Log.d("SMSReceiver", str); And run. if not marking this as my favorite question to see the answer :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that there are several buffers for log messages.  The tags decide which buffer these logs go into.  According to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/9011945/1475461 SMS is one of those tags that gets put into a different buffer.

The other buffer can be viewed with the following command

```
adb logcat -b radio
```

Thanks to @nKn for getting me along the right tracks.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an old known issue when you use `Log.*` in combination with a tag called `SMS`. There seems not logical explaination to this but your code is working accordingly, it's just the `Log.d()` line that is not working correctly.

You should replace the tag `SMS` with some other, in that case it should work as expected (in this case, avoiding the bug).

Comment: Is this bug reported anywhere?

Comment: Ah infact, from your answer I have found another answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8699756/logcat-not-displaying-tag-sms which explains that the issue is not a bug, but seperate buffers into which the logs go.

Comment: I remembered I had read similar questions to yours several times, not I've tried looking for an official bug but no luck, seems that the question you just found is the most reasonable explaination for this.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me out suggesting that SMS specifically does not work.